# What does the sklearn PCA to the input array when when the number of components is choose to be the same?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

for example we have:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np 

xx = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA()
pca.fit_transform(xx)
```

otput:

```
array([[ 1.38340578,  0.2935787 ],
   [ 2.22189802, -0.25133484],
   [ 3.6053038 ,  0.04224385],
   [-1.38340578, -0.2935787 ],
   [-2.22189802,  0.25133484],
   [-3.6053038 , -0.04224385]])
```

In this case i am not reducing the size however the array is changed... why?

Comment: Please think about asking theory of statistics on [stats.se]. As well, please consider [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA does a linear (rotation) transformation of your feature space.  In your case,
assume feature 1 is along `x` and feature 2 is along `y`, the resulting transformation is the same as a rotating your feature vectors through an angle of `theta` ~ 2.565 radians.  Below I've defined such a rotation matrix and show you get the same result:

```
import numpy as np
def rot_matrix(theta):
    # returns rotation matrix through angle theta
    rotation_matrix = np.dot(np.array([[np.cos(theta), -

np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
        return rotation_matrix

theta = 2.565
rot = rot_matrix(theta)
np.dot(rot, xx.T).T
```

result is (close to) the output of the PCA transform:

```
array([[ 1.38349574,  0.29315446],
       [ 2.22182084, -0.25201619],
       [ 3.60531658,  0.04113827],
       [-1.38349574, -0.29315446],
       [-2.22182084,  0.25201619],
       [-3.60531658, -0.04113827]])
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! i would like to know how does this should effect the error if i decide to perform this rotation on a training dataset? i mean i have tried and i get nearby same results for root mean squared error... does it makes sense?? is this similar to try to reduce noise in the data?